# How To Show Second Row Using Pandas in Python With Duplicate Row Names

Tags: python, pandas, excel, row

I am writing a script to read from an Excel sheet, that I can't modify, that has several duplicate rows.

The issue I am having is that it appears to stop adding to the index after finding the first row.

I can't figure out how to get it skip the first row and index only the second.

```
 df = pd.read_excel(aisc_excel_file)

    # Open the profiles.lis file for writing
    with open(profiles_lis_file, 'w') as profiles_lis:
        # Write the header to the profiles.lis file
        profiles_lis.write("PROFILE\tWIDTH\tHEIGHT\n")

        # Iterate through rows in the AISC DataFrame and write to profiles.lis
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            profile_name = row['AISC_Manual_Label']
            width = row['h, in']
            height = row['b, in']

            # Write the profile data to the profiles.lis file
            profiles_lis.write(f"{profile_name}\t{width}\t{height}\n")
```

Here is the AISC Excel sheet:
https://www.aisc.org/globalassets/product-files-not-searched/manuals/aisc-shapes-database-v16.0.xlsx

I have two "AISC_Manual_Label" row labels, I need the data from the second.

I have tried the df.Duplicated but it always returns a boolean and the index stays the same.

I also read something about series but was not able to get the second row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What you asked is highly unclear. For starters, what is the output of `df.head(10).to_dict('tight')`? Please [edit] your question with the output of this command.

Comment: can you please provide an example so we help?

Comment: otherwise, try to play around with `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ColumnName"], keep="first")` check the documentation for other types of `keep`

Comment: Question updated with more information.

Comment: I need to keep both of them, one of them is the imperial name and one is the metric name, so I think series would work best, from what I read they should get indexed accordingly so row.0 to row.1 but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @mozway Output of the requested command: https://pastebin.com/G5stmwPr

Comment: @mozway, that actually helped answer my question, thank you so much!

Comment: @JudeAustin, I think you're conflating between "*rows*" and "*columns*". The spreadsheet `Database v16.0` have duplicated columns names (such as `AISC_Manual_Label`, columns `C` and `CH`) and not rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to select a subset of columns and make a [tab-separated-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) file. If so, you can simply select the columns, then call [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
subset = df[["AISC_Manual_Label.1", "h.1", "b.1"]] # adjust if needed

# subset.to_csv("output.txt", sep="\t") # uncomment to make a file
```

NB: In the original spreadsheet, if there are duplicated headers (which is the case here), pandas deduplicates them by appending a suffix increment (`.\d+`), such as `colx` (1st occurence), `colx.1` (2nd occurence), `colx.2` (3rd occurence), and so on..

Preview of (`df`) :

```
      Type EDI_Std_Nomenclature AISC_Manual_Label  ...  T.1  WGi.1  WGo.1
0        W              W44X408           W44X408  ...  965    140  76.20
1        W              W44X368           W44X368  ...  965    140  76.20
2        W              W44X335           W44X335  ...  965    140  76.20
...    ...                  ...               ...  ...  ...    ...    ...
2296  PIPE             Pipe3XXS          Pipe3XXS  ...    –      –      –
2297  PIPE         Pipe2-1/2XXS      Pipe2-1/2XXS  ...    –      –      –
2298  PIPE             Pipe2XXS          Pipe2XXS  ...    –      –      –

[2299 rows x 166 columns]
```

Used input :

```
url = "https://www.aisc.org/globalassets/product-files-not-searched/" \
      "manuals/aisc-shapes-database-v16.0.xlsx"

from io import BytesIO; import requests
data = BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)

df = pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name="Database v16.0")
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could use AISC_Manual_Label.1 instead of AISC_Manual_Label to get the second header. That is what I was confused about and that is why mozways output helped me, haha.